# Web element reference not seen before

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to make a web-scraper that fetches all the results of every google search, however it kept outputting a "web element reference not seen before error". I assume it's due to the code trying to find the element before the url loads, but i am not too sure how to fix it.

```
from selenium import webdriver

#number of pages
max_page = 5

#number of digits (ie: 2 is 1 digit, 10 is 2 digits)
max_dig = 1

#Open up firefox browser
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#inputs search into google 
question = input("\n What would you like to google today, but replace every space with a '+' (ie: search+this)\n\n")

search = [] 

#get multiple pages
for i in range(0, max_page + 1):
    #inserts page number into google search
    page_num = (max_dig - len(str(i))) * "0" + str(i)
    #inserts search input and cycles through pages
    url =  "https://www.google.com/search?q="+ question +"&ei=LV-uXYrpNoj0rAGC8KSYCg&start="+ page_num +"0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjKs8ie367lAhUIOisKHQI4CaM4ChDy0wMIiQE&biw=1356&bih=946"
    #finds element in every search page
    search+=(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('LC20lb'))
    driver.get(url)

#print results
search_items = len(search)
for a in range(search_items):
    #print the page number
    print(type(search[a].text))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "screwdriver.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(type(search[b].text))
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Web element reference not seen before: 6187cf00-39c8-c14b-a2de-b1d24e965b65
```

Comment: why don't use use `for item in search:` instead of `for a in range(len(search)): search[a]`

Comment: problem can be `get()` - Selenium doesn't keep HTML which you found but rather reference to elemen on page. When you load next page (`get()`) then reference refers to item which doesn't exists on new page. You should get text from item befor you load new page.

Comment: ah thank for the help, i managed to get it working about replacing the second for loop with your suggestion, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that `Selenium` doesn't keep HTML which you found but rather referece to element on current page. When you load new page - `get()` - then reference try to find element on new page and it can't find it. You should get text (and any other information) from item before you load new page.

```
from selenium import webdriver

max_page = 5

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

question = input("\n What would you like to google today, but replace every space with a '+' (ie: search+this)\n\n")

search = [] 

for i in range(max_page+1):
    page_num = str(i)

    url =  "https://www.google.com/search?q="+ question +"&ei=LV-uXYrpNoj0rAGC8KSYCg&start="+ page_num +"0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjKs8ie367lAhUIOisKHQI4CaM4ChDy0wMIiQE&biw=1356&bih=946"

    items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('LC20lb')

    for item in items:
        search.append(item.text) 

    driver.get(url)

for item in search:
    print(item)
```